# Latest version of MariaDB 10.4.7 does not launch on Windows 10

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have been using MariaDB locally on my machine for development purposes using the extracted zip version (e.g. mariadb-10.3.17-winx64.zip). This has worked flawlessly while on 10.3.x

Have attempted to run 10.4.7 in the same manner, but it fails to start with the following console output.

`D:\Downloads\mariadb-10.4.7-winx64\mariadb-10.4.7-winx64\bin>.\mysqld --console
2019-08-31  7:11:58 0 [Note] .\mysqld (mysqld 10.4.7-MariaDB) starting as process 18976 ...
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2019-08-31  7:11:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-08-31  7:11:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-08-31  7:11:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-08-31  7:11:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-08-31  7:11:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-08-31  7:11:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2019-08-31  7:11:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-08-31  7:11:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-08-31  7:11:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-08-31  7:11:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '.\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-08-31  7:11:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '.\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-08-31  7:11:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.7 started; log sequence number 114269; transaction id 9
2019-08-31  7:11:58 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-08-31  7:11:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\Downloads\mariadb-10.4.7-winx64\mariadb-10.4.7-winx64\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-08-31  7:11:58 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
2019-08-31  7:11:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 190831  7:11:58
2019-08-31  7:11:58 0 [ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist
2019-08-31  7:11:59 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2019-08-31  7:11:59 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.db' doesn't exist
2019-08-31  7:11:59 0 [ERROR] Aborting`